# Input inside Android WebView with randomly focus

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, android-13

I'm fighting with a problem on Android WebView..
I have a WebPage that is kinda a form, with 8 inputs and a button, and I load this page on a WebView on my mobile app
For iOS it works perfectly
For web it works perfectly,

But for android, most specifically for Android 13 the focus of the fields are totally random
I mean, if I'm on the first field, and tap on the second one, the focus goes to third field, if I click on the fourth the focus goes to the first...
For most part of the android devices it works also, but obviously on my boss phone it don't haha
Trying on emulator and devices here I saw that it's just happens on some android devices with OS version Android 13
And I really don't know what more I can do.

I saw a lot of question related to this with this answer:

```
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) { 
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                       if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                           v.requestFocus(); 
                       } 
                       break; 
               } 
               return false; 
            }
    });
```

but this don't work as well
Anyone here already saw something like that ? Know how to fix ?
Thanks